# Error con la session storage en PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, cookies

Tengo mi HTML y mi archivo PHP. Cuando el usuario se dirige a la tienda.php, este es el código:

```
<header>
        <nav
            class="bgPersonalizedColor fixed top-0 left-0 z-20 w-full border-b border-gray-200 bg-white py-2.5 px-6 sm:px-4">
            <div class="container mx-auto flex max-w-6xl flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
                <a href="#" class="w-1/6 flex items-center">
                    <img src="img/logoStrant.png" alt="">

                    <span class="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="mt-2 sm:mt-0 sm:flex md:order-2">
                    <!-- Login Button -->
                    <button type="button"
                        class="rounde mr-3 hidden border border-green-500 py-1.5 px-6 text-center text-sm font-medium text-green-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 md:inline-block rounded-lg btnHeaderInicioSesion">Inicio
                        Sesión</button>
                    <button type="button"
                        class="rounde mr-3 hidden bg-green-500 py-1.5 px-6 text-center text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-green-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-green-300 md:mr-0 md:inline-block rounded-lg  btnHeaderInicioSesion">Registrar</button>
                    <!-- Register Button -->
                    <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-sticky" type="button"
                        class="inline-flex items-center rounded-lg p-2 text-sm text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 md:hidden"
                        aria-controls="navbar-sticky" aria-expanded="false" id="toggleButton">
                        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                        <svg class="h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M3 5a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 10a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1zM3 15a1 1 0 011-1h12a1 1 0 110 2H4a1 1 0 01-1-1z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden w-full items-center justify-between md:order-1 md:flex md:w-auto" id="navbar-sticky">
                    <ul
                        class="mt-4 flex flex-col rounded-lg border border-gray-100 bg-gray-50 p-4 md:mt-0 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 md:border-0 md:bg-white md:text-sm md:font-medium">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"
                                class="block rounded bg-green-500 py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-white md:bg-transparent md:p-0 md:text-blue-700"
                                aria-current="page">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"
                                class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 md:p-0 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-green-700">Nosotros</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"
                                class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 md:p-0 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-green-700">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"
                                class="block rounded py-2 pl-3 pr-4 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 md:p-0 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-green-700">Tienda</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="pt-32  bg-white">
        <h1 class="text-center text-2xl font-bold text-gray-800">Todos nuestros productos</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Product List -->
    <section class="py-10 bg-gray-100">
        <div class="mx-auto grid max-w-6xl  grid-cols-1 gap-6 p-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
            <?php include "productos.php"; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Este es mi código de productos.php:

```
<?php session_start();
$host = "[hereGoesHost]";
$username = "[usernameGoesHere]";
$password = "[passwordGoesHere]";
$dbname = "u611396439_productos";
// Crea la conexión
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Verifica la conexión
if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(isset($_COOKIE['nombre_cookie']) && isset($_SESSION['usuario_logueado'])) {
        echo '<article
        class="rounded-xl bg-white p-3 shadow-lg hover:shadow-xl hover:transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 ">
      
        <div class="relative flex items-end overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="' .$row['imagen'] . '" alt="'.$row['descripcion'].'" />
            <div
                class="flex items-center space-x-1.5 rounded-lg bg-green-500 px-4 py-1.5 text-white duration-100 bg-green-600">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                    stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                        d="M2.25 3h1.386c.51 0 .955.343 1.087.835l.383 1.437M7.5 14.25a3 3 0 00-3 3h15.75m-12.75-3h11.218c1.121-2.3 2.1-4.684 2.924-7.138a60.114 60.114 0 00-16.536-1.84M7.5 14.25L5.106 5.272M6 20.25a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zm12.75 0a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0z" />
                </svg>
      
                <button class="text-sm">Agregar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="mt-1 p-2">
            <h2 class="text-slate-700">'.$row['descripcion'].'</h2>
            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-slate-400">'.$row['categoria'].'</p>
      
            <div class="mt-3 flex items-end justify-between">
                <p class="text-lg font-bold text-blue-500">$'.$row['precio'].'</p>
      
                <div
                    class="flex items-center space-x-1.5 rounded-lg bg-green-500 px-4 py-1.5 text-white duration-100 bg-green-600">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                        stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                            d="M2.25 3h1.386c.51 0 .955.343 1.087.835l.383 1.437M7.5 14.25a3 3 0 00-3 3h15.75m-12.75-3h11.218c1.121-2.3 2.1-4.684 2.924-7.138a60.114 60.114 0 00-16.536-1.84M7.5 14.25L5.106 5.272M6 20.25a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zm12.75 0a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0z" />
                    </svg>
      
                    <button class="text-sm" id="addToCart" onclick="addToCart('.$row['id'].')">Agregar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
      </article>';
      

      } else {
        echo '<article
        class="rounded-xl bg-white p-3 shadow-lg hover:shadow-xl hover:transform hover:scale-105 duration-300 ">
      
        <div class="relative flex items-end overflow-hidden rounded-xl">
            <img src="' .$row['imagen'] . '" alt="'.$row['descripcion'].'" />
            <div
                class="flex items-center space-x-1.5 rounded-lg bg-green-500 px-4 py-1.5 text-white duration-100 bg-green-600">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                    stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                        d="M2.25 3h1.386c.51 0 .955.343 1.087.835l.383 1.437M7.5 14.25a3 3 0 00-3 3h15.75m-12.75-3h11.218c1.121-2.3 2.1-4.684 2.924-7.138a60.114 60.114 0 00-16.536-1.84M7.5 14.25L5.106 5.272M6 20.25a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zm12.75 0a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0z" />
                </svg>
      
                <button class="text-sm">Agregar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="mt-1 p-2">
            <h2 class="text-slate-700">'.$row['descripcion'].'</h2>
            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-slate-400">'.$row['categoria'].'</p>
      
            <div class="mt-3 flex items-end justify-between">
                <p class="text-lg font-bold text-blue-500">$'.$row['precio'].'</p>
      
                <div
                    class="flex items-center space-x-1.5 rounded-lg bg-green-500 px-4 py-1.5 text-white duration-100 bg-green-600">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5"
                        stroke="currentColor" class="h-4 w-4">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                            d="M2.25 3h1.386c.51 0 .955.343 1.087.835l.383 1.437M7.5 14.25a3 3 0 00-3 3h15.75m-12.75-3h11.218c1.121-2.3 2.1-4.684 2.924-7.138a60.114 60.114 0 00-16.536-1.84M7.5 14.25L5.106 5.272M6 20.25a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0zm12.75 0a.75.75 0 11-1.5 0 .75.75 0 011.5 0z" />
                    </svg>
      
                    <a href="iniciarsesion.html">Agregar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      
      </article>';
      }
  }
}

// Cierra la conexión
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Lo que hace el archivo PHP además de obtener los productos que se encuentran en mi base de datos, es dependiendo si el usuario ha iniciado sesión o no es mostrar un botón diferente. Si ha iniciado sesión, le permitirá agregar al carrito, si no lo ha hecho le redirigirá al inicio de sesion.

Pero cuando abro el archivo en el servidor, el de tienda, se muestra el siguiente mensaje:
Warning:session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in
/home/u611396439/domains/strant.store/public_html/productos.php on line 1

Quisiera saber por qué se debe esto.

Comment: Asegúrate que fuera de las etiquetas <?php y ?> No tengas un carácter perdido tipo un espacio o un carácter no imprimible

Comment: No tengo ningún caracter no imprimible fuera de las etiquetas. Eso es lo que llama mi atención.

Comment: Lo has pasado por un hexeditor?

Comment: Sí, lo he pasado por hexed.it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estaba escondido y no lo había visto

```
<section class="py-10 bg-gray-100">
    <div class="mx-auto grid max-w-6xl  grid-cols-1 gap-6 p-6 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
        <?php include "productos.php"; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Estas encadenando dos ficheros por eso ya enviaste las headers, tienes que poner el session_start en el principio del fichero tienda.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<header>
        <nav
            class="bgPersonalizedColor fixed top-0 left-0 z-20 w-full border-b border-gray-200 bg-white py-2.5 px-6 sm:px-4">
            <div class="container mx-auto flex max-w-6xl flex-wrap items-center justify-between">
                <a href="#" class="w-1/6 flex items-center">
                    <img src="img/logoStrant.png" alt="">

                    <span class="self-center whitespace-nowrap text-xl font-semibold"></span>
                </a> ....
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Saludos!